# Mentioning column names in select for derived tables

Tags: t-sql

i have doubt,

```
select *   
from  
(  
     select *  
     (  
         select User_Id,User_Name,Password  
         from <table> T  
         where  IsActive = 1  
     ) k   
) m
```

in this case, is it required to mention column names in other 2 select statements,

mentioning columns is always better than keeping *

but,what is the use actually in above top 2 selects as we are getting selected columns from derived tables..

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to mention each column instead of doing `SELECT * FROM`. However, if you don't need all columns you can optimize by selecting only the columns you need: `SELECT a, b, c FROM`.

There's no value added or optimization in having two nested `SELECT *` without any sort of calculation. Here's an article on [Transact-SQL Derived Tables](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1251e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/12932) where I recommend you check out the **Advantages of SQL derived tables** section. There's a good example in there.